# How to import Sybase .db file into SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sybase, import

I've been given a Sybase `.db` file by a client and I need to import that into a new SQL Server database so that I may see the data as well as the tables and their relationships, any ideas on how that might be done shall be really appreciated :)

Comment: You need a Sybase server

Answer (score 2):

Since both Sybase and SQLServer share the same SQL dialect (T-SQL), I'd generate the DDL statements from the existing database (it will require a Sybase server) to build the SQL Server database and the an SSIS task to copy data between databases.

I don't know if it is possible to SQLServer to just open a Sybase file, but, albeit the same origins, I don't believe there's any kind of binary compatibility between inner formats of this two DBMS.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Sybase **ddlgen** utilitly to extract the database structure, datatypes, etc.  Then use the Sybase **bcp** utility to extract the data from the Sybase database.  Once you have those two things, you can build the database in SQLServer, and import the data.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a dump file, load it into a development database using the *load* command. Alternatively you can use a working production system to obtain a new dump. You can the transfer it from the sybase db to the ms sql server db using Microsoft's SSMA tool.

The download link for SSMA is below.
[Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant v5.3 for MySQL](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42657)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant (SSMA) for MySQL is a tool to automate migration from MySQL database to SQL Server! not for sybase

Comment: @imanabidi why is it not good for sybase ? I have been using it for all my migrations from sybase to SQL Server and it works excellently.