# How to transfer data from Sybase to SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sybase

url reference [How to import Sybase .db file into SQL Server database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25355/how-to-import-sybase-db-file-into-sql-server-database)

Please tell me how to transfer data from sybase to sql server database.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question multiple times.  And please don't add your email address into posts unless you are begging for spam.

Comment: One way you can accomplish the transfer might be to use bcp to copy individual tables from Sybase into SQL Server.  Another might be to use Linked Servers from SQL Server to the Sybase Server.

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1**: You can use ODBC connections to create an SSIS package which will fetch the data from SYBASE database onto SQL server. On how to use or create such SSIS Package read [Extracting data from Sybase SQL Anywhere using SSIS through ODBC](http://supun-biz.blogspot.in/2010/11/extracting-data-from-sybase-sql.html).
Then Schedule the above created package via SQL agent job to update data on SQL server as per schedule which meets the requirement.

**Method 2**: You can create a Linked server which fetches the required data from Sybase to SQL as described [here](http://sql-articles.com/articles/dba/creating-linked-server-to-sybase-from-sql-server/).

And then create a job executing the task that refresh data from SQL Anywhere onto SQL Server using [OPENQUERY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)